# What are the updates to be done in SP 2013 after migrating from SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

After Migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, what are the classes that are required to be changed in SharePoint 2013. The View, New and Edit forms are not displaying properly after migration.
What are the changes to be made in default.aspx page as shown in images below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, have you run the upgrade of site collection on SP2013?

Comment: Yes, we have upgraded the site collection from SP2010(Site Definitions, List Definitions implemented through Visual Studio) to SP2013